# Proof of A ⊆ C and B ⊆ C ⇔ A ∪ B ⊆ C

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that this is valid because by thinking about it, you can see it's true, but I'm just not sure how I would go about actually proving it mathematically. I've kind of tried proof by contradiction, since that's what I use most of the time, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my mind, A ∪ B ⊆ C kind of just implies that A ⊆ C and B ⊆ C.

Comment: Try a direct proof in each direction instead. You prove $X\subseteq Y$ by assuming that $p\in X$ and from that assumption proving $p\in Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally, you can still proceed by contradiction.  Suppose $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, but somehow $A \cup B \not\subseteq C$.  Then there must be an element $x \in A \cup B$ such that $x \not\in C$.  There are two possibilities: either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ (or both are true).  If $x \in A$, then $x \in C$, by the premise.  But if $x \in B$, then also $x \in C$, again by premise.  Either way, $x \in C$ necessarily.  This is a contradiction, so our assumption that there existed such an $x$ must be false, and $A \cup B \subseteq C$ indeed.

The other direction can be done similarly.  But I agree that the direct proof is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Work from the definitions. For proving that $(A \subseteq C) \wedge (B \subseteq C)$ implies $(A \cup B) \subseteq C$, assume that $(A \subseteq C)$ and $(B \subseteq C)$, then consider the definition of a generic element of $(A \cup B)$. For the converse, assume $(A \cup B) \subseteq C$, consider a generic element of $A$ (or $B$), show that it's an element of $A \cup B$, then show that it's also an element of $C$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A \subseteq C $ and $ B \subseteq C $. That means $\forall x \in A, x\in C$ and $\forall y \in B, y\in $. Hence, $\forall z \in A \cup B, z\in C$

Let $ x\in A \subseteq A \cup B\subseteq C$, it is clear that $x \in C$.

Let $ y\in B \subseteq A \cup B\subseteq C$, it is clear that $y \in C$.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a tautology:
$$
((p\to r)\land(q\to r)) \leftrightarrow ((p\lor q)\to r),
$$
as you can easily confirm. Taking $p := x\in A$, $q:= x\in B$, $r := x\in C$ gives:
$$
((x\in A\to x\in C)\land(x\in B\to x\in C)) \leftrightarrow ((x\in A\lor x\in B)\to x\in C).
$$
You can universally quantified both sides of the biconditional, preserving equivalence:
$$
\forall x ((x\in A\to x\in C)\land(x\in B\to x\in C)) \leftrightarrow \forall x ((x\in A\lor x\in B)\to x\in C).
$$
Because, $\forall$ distributes over $\land$ ($\forall$ is a form of "and"), the above can be written:
$$
(\forall x(x\in A\to x\in C)\land \forall x(x\in B\to x\in C)) \leftrightarrow \forall x ((x\in A\lor x\in B)\to x\in C).\tag{*}
$$
Finally, note that (*) says what you want to prove:
$$
(A\subseteq C \land B \subseteq C) \leftrightarrow (A\cup B\subseteq C).
$$